# Returning multiple values from sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm trying to return 4 variables from a stored procedure to a page in ASP.Net VB Script. It's only returning the first result then breaking. My knowledge of SQL is limited. I have tried the following:

SQL:

```
Alter PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spDashboardPaymentRequests]
@id integer
AS
SELECT COUNT(Receiptno) as requestsSent
FROM [demofeepay3].[dbo].[vwallrequests]
Where Orgid = @id

SELECT Sum(totamount) as requestTotal
FROM [demofee].[dbo].[vwallrequests]
Where Orgid = @id

SELECT Sum(totamount) as requestTotalPaid
FROM [demofee].[dbo].[vwallrequests]
Where Orgid = @id AND status = 'paid'

SELECT Sum(totamount) as requestTotalUnpaid
FROM [demo].[dbo].[vwallrequests]
Where Orgid = @id AND status = 'unpaid'
```

ASP.NET

```
Function RequestsSent()
    Dim objCmd2 As sqlCommand
    Dim objRdr2 As sqlDataReader
    objCmd2 = New SqlCommand("spDashboardPaymentRequests", objConn)
    objCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orgid", Session("orgid"))
    objConn.Open()
    objRdr2 = objCmd2.ExecuteReader
    objRdr2.Read()
    Session("RequestsSent") = objRdr2("requestsSent")
    Session("RequestsTotal") = objRdr2("requestTotal")
    Session("RequestsTotalPaid") = objRdr2("requestTotalPaid")
    Session("RequestsTotalUnpaid") = objRdr2("requestTotalUnpaid")
    objConn.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: Instead of a function make it a method, you are not returning anything. Declare some output params for your direction and set them in SQL... Also that sql can be reduced into 1 statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple `select`s which means multiple result-sets. So you have to move through them:

```
objRdr2.Read()
Session("RequestsSent") = objRdr2("requestsSent")

objRdr2.NextResult()
objRdr2.Read()
Session("RequestsTotal") = objRdr2("requestTotal")

objRdr2.NextResult()
objRdr2.Read()
Session("RequestsTotalPaid") = objRdr2("requestTotalPaid")

objRdr2.NextResult()
objRdr2.Read()
Session("RequestsTotalUnpaid") = objRdr2("requestTotalUnpaid")
```

Or, you can change the sproc to return one resultset with multiple columns:

```
Alter PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spDashboardPaymentRequests]
@id integer
AS
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(Receiptno) FROM [demofeepay3].[dbo].[vwallrequests] Where Orgid = @id) 
    as requestsSent,

    (SELECT Sum(totamount) FROM [demofee].[dbo].[vwallrequests] Where Orgid = @id) 
    as requestTotal,

    (SELECT Sum(totamount) FROM [demofee].[dbo].[vwallrequests] Where Orgid = @id AND status = 'paid')
    as requestTotalPaid,

    (SELECT Sum(totamount) FROM [demo].[dbo].[vwallrequests] Where Orgid = @id AND status = 'unpaid')
    as requestTotalUnpaid
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about asp , but you probably do, so here is a query to get all of them as the same row , adjust your asp code accordingly:

```
SELECT COUNT(Receiptno) as requestsSent,
       (SELECT Sum(totamount) 
        FROM [demofee].[dbo].[vwallrequests]
        Where Orgid = @id) as requestTotal,
       --Query 3,
       --Query 4
FROM [demofeepay3].[dbo].[vwallrequests]
Where Orgid = @id
```

Comment: Cheers mate, will try this, and let you know :-)